# Cross threading exception avoided but GUI isn't updating

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have a thread which needs to update a Windows form.  Using the code from here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/143/entry-2337-handling-the-dreaded-cross-thread-exception/

to avoid cross-threading exceptions.

I've got the controls updating but the GUI isn't refreshing to show the new values.  To confirm that they are updating I'm reading their values, setting them and then reading them again printing out the result on both occasions.

Here's my code (this is contained within the thread library) to add a custom event which I can use to trigger a thread-safe update to any control:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module MyInvoke
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub CustomInvoke(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke)(ByVal control As T, ByVal toPerform As Action(Of T))
        If control.InvokeRequired Then
            control.Invoke(toPerform, New Object() {control})
        Else
            toPerform(control)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

When the thread forces an update, this is how it does it:

```
' Read initial label text and write it out
Dim labelText As String = Form1.Label1.Text
Console.WriteLine("Label: " & labelText)

' Change value of label text, re-read it and write it out
Form1.Label1.CustomInvoke(Sub(l) l.Text = "Hello World")
labelText = Form1.Label1.Text
Console.WriteLine("Label: " & labelText)
```

This code changes the text but it doesn't update in the GUI - it still shows as 'Label1'.  If I trigger the thread again it correctly reads the changed value (Hello World) but it's still not updated in the GUI (that still shows Label1).

I've tried refreshing it: Form1.Label1.CustomInvoke(Sub(l) l.Refresh()) without success.  What am I doing wrong ?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
    Label1.CustomInvoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "hello")
```